# remove document including image in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following document schema

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({
    category_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    icon_url: { type: String, required: true },
})
```

method to delete a file

```
deleteSingle(fileNameWithPath: string) {
        fs.unlink(fileNameWithPath, function(err) {
            if(err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
                console.info("File doesn't exist");
            } else if (err) {
                console.error("Error occurred while trying to remove file");
            } else {
                console.info('File has been removed');
            }
        });
    }
```

I can delete a document with the following method but don't know how to remove a file too using above `deleteSingle()` method.

```
router.delete('/:category', async (req, res) => { // removes the category
    try {
        let category = await CategorySchema
            .findOneAndRemove({
                 category_id: req.params.category
     }
   }    
})
```

> `path` for image is a folder `uploads` in the root directory. Thus it would be something like this `'uploads/image.png'`

any suggestions to remove a document including a file.

Comment: So how does `icon_url` relate to the running path of the application? Is there a relative path to where the file is actually stored in which that can be applied?

Comment: yeah, it's relative path. using multer to save a file

Comment: What is the relative path ? Is it just from the root? `/` as current directory, or is it in something like `./public` under the application directory?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: my mistake it is `absolut path`. this folder is in the project's root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandremove_findOneAndRemove) method is going to return the document which is being removed, so then you just use the `icon_url` property in order to pass in the relative path to the actual file.

But your wrapping function is not much use here since it's using resolution in a callback. Instead, use something with a Promise. The [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) library already wraps `fs` and other built in libraries with Promises:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const path = require('path');

router.delete('/:category', async (req, res) => { // removes the category
  try {
    let category = await CategorySchema.findOneAndRemove({
      category_id: req.params.category
    });
    await fs.unlink(path.resolve(__dirname, category.icon_url));
    // then send response
  } catch(e) {
    // handle error responses here
  }
})
```

Or you can wrap the standard `fs.unlink` in a Promise yourself:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

router.delete('/:category', async (req, res) => { // removes the category
  try {
    let category = await CategorySchema.findOneAndRemove({
      category_id: req.params.category
    });
    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
      fs.unlink(path.resolve(__dirname, category.icon_url),(err) => 
        (err) ? reject(err) : resolve())
    );
    // then send response
  } catch(e) {
    // handle error responses here
  }
})
```

> **NOTE** - In preference you really should use `findOneAndDelete()` instead with modern API's. That method actually uses the official API call rather than the deprecated direct use of `findAndModify` which the `findOneAndRemove()` method does.

Comment: @MWN The only possible issue is the running path of your application and where `uploads` is actually relative to. That might need adjusting.

Comment: What is `mz/fs`. Why you preferred `mz/fs` over `fs`. Can you provide a short description or a link.

Comment: @MWN There is one. Hover over the `mz` in the answer

Comment: In `fs.unlink()`, reolve method is unavailable. correct one is `fs.unlink(path.resolve(__dirname, fileNameWithPath), (err) =>
                reject(err)
            )` because in `typescript`,  `reject` method was giving `compile time error`.